# error occurs when saving new posts in mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

```
const userSchema = {
email: String,
password: String,
post:{
    title: String,
    content: String
}};
```

unable to access the post field and save data on it how  suppose to do that

```
const title = req.body.title;
const content = req.body.content;

newPost = new User({
    post.title:title,
    content.content:content
});
```

by doing this way error occurs when saving the new post to post obj

Comment: You missed the post object to declare first and also there is no content object and you are trying to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the `User` object first and then access those nested props like:

```
const title = req.body.title;
const content = req.body.content;

let newPost = new User();
newPost.post.title = title;
newPost.post.content = content;
```

or, minimise it like:

```
let newPost = new User();
newPost.post = { title: title, content: content };
```

but, as both key and value are same here, you can also use object-shorthand like:

```
let newPost = new User();
newPost.post = { title, content };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to access `title` and `content` without declaring an `post` object. 
So you can declare `post` object and them assign value to each attribute.

In your case, there is no `content` object and you are trying to access it like  `content.content`.

Please use the following code

```
  let post = {};

  newPost = new User({
     post.title:title,
     post.content:content
  });
```

Also would like to suggest you create separate `Post` schema as a single user will have multiple posts, So you don't need to create user each time.

Example

```
    const postSchema = {
        userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        title: String,
        content: String
    };
```

And simply you can create the Post as follows,

```
    const { title, content } = req.body;
    const userId = req.body.userId;// login user id or which user want to create a post

    newPost = new Post({ title, content});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: one follow up ques sir ,  when we say  const userId = req.body.userId; we never identify the post with the particular user can you please littile elaborate that and as you say above   "Also would like to suggest you create separate Post schema as a single user will have multiple posts, So you don't need to create user each time."  this is exactly what am tyrin to do here please help if you can.

Comment: I just gave an example to you get userId from the body, which is coming from the client-side.  Normally we have to create middleware over that API which we will check valid user.

Comment: Please check this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/route-middleware-to-check-if-a-user-is-authenticated-in-node-js and you will get the user object from req.user